# Showing images in a UITableView with prototype cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I want to make a `UITableView` with all members of a guild of mine. I have it configured to show information like name, address, phone, etc. But I also want to show two pictures of each person: 1) one with their portrait and 2) another with their emblem. I don't know what kind of type I have to give the UIImageViews for it to work.

With this code it's showing an error, that `UIImageView` is an undeclared type.

```
import Foundation

struct Person {
    var name: String?
    var profession: String?
    var addressBlockOne: String?
    var addressBlockTwo: String?
    var phoneNumberPrivate: String?
    var phoneNumberMobile: String?
    var phoneNumberWork: String?
    var mail: String?
    var birthday: String?
    var admission: String?
    var portraitView: UIImageView?
    var emblemView: UIImageView?
}
```

**EDIT:**
I have now imported the UIKit and changed the UIImageView to UIImage. It's all working without error. But When I want to put a Image in the UIImageView, it doesn't show it in the simulator. Here is the Test for the TableCell:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class PersonService {

private let persons: [Person] = [
    Person( name: "xy",
            profession: "yx",
            addressBlockOne: "street xy",
            addressBlockTwo: "yx",
            phoneNumberPrivate: "xxxx",
            phoneNumberMobile: "yyyy",
            phoneNumberWork: "-",
            mail: "zz@gmail.com",
            birthday: "xy",
            admission: "yx",
            portraitView: UIImage(named: "xy"),
            emblemView: UIImage(named: "yx")
    )
```

**EDIT 2:**
It's not a problem with the constrain. The problem is, that it now only shows a picture when I put one in the UIImageView over the Storyboard ans it shows for all members the same picture.

Comment: The `UIImageView` is just a place to put the image. You still need to tell the imageView what image you'll be using in it.

Comment: Sorry, i'm just a beginner. I don't have much experience. For what is coming inside the Textfields I have made an other file where I give all members the infos. So first I have to give the UIImageViews a Type so the programm knows what I can put inside. Or am I wrong with that? The other variables are working perfectly fine when I give them a type string, but what type do I need fore a Image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add **import UIKit** to your file?

To use any apps UI(User Interface) element you need to import UIKit in your controller.

Reference : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKit_Framework/

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped

Comment: @Thobbit i am not getting your question ?Can you explain it in brief ?

Comment: It's just like it's not loading the images. their are saved in the project but dont show in the UIImageView when I put them in the Code like this

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the image as UIImage in the Person struct - in exactly the same way as you store the name in a String, and not in a UITextView or UILabel

Comment: That I have understood know, thx. My next problem is up in the editet question.

Comment: ok - which bit is failing?  It could either be that you haven't loaded the data initially, or that you're not displaying it

have you confirmed that the Person struct is being correctly populated first?
have you confirmed that the image view is displayed correctly - sometimes with incorrect constraints, the image view will end up at (0,0) with size (0,0), which isn't good.  You can always check your imageviews by setting a default image at design time

Comment: The data has to be loaded, because it shows all infos like name, profession, etc. perfectly fine. The constraints should also be good, it looks fine when I put in a image over the storyboard, but it doesn't show if I put it in programmatically

Comment: good that the strings are all loaded ok, but you need to specifically check the image variables - you won't be able to see the image itself (I wish you could!) but you should be able to see is something has been loaded.  Remember - you're doing more with loading the images than just setting a string.  You have to be sure that the images were loaded into the resource bundle correctly, and that you're loading it with the right name at run-time

Comment: i have drag and droped the Images in the project. The Name is copy pasted and should be right. Can I see somewhere, if the images are loaded?

Comment: set a breakpoint in your code just before you assign the data - take a look at the UIImage variable, and the step over the data load.  If you don't see the description of your variable changing, then you know you haven't loaded it correctly.

Comment: I have tried all I can, it hasn't showed anything in the console or any other information. I dont get it

Comment: I have found my fail. I didn't know you have to wright the .png at the and of the image name. I feal a little bit dumb right now. Thanks for your help.